# Compute the integral of $ z^2+ z z*$ where $C=\{ z | |z|=1, 0<argz<\pi \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

(Z* is z-conjugate)

This has been my attempt: 
I have let $z=e^{(it)}$ for $0<t<\pi$

So then i get that $z^2+ z z* = e^{(2it)}+1$ and that $ dz=ie^{(it)} dt$
I formed my integral with these facts, to attain $ie^{(3it)}+ie^{(it)}$
from 0 to $\pi$
Calculating this as a normal integral got me -8/3
However I do not feel I have gone about this the right way??

Comment: $|z|<1$ or $|z|=1$?

Comment: Sorry |z|=1 is what the question states

Comment: So, your substitution for z is ok. Can you figure out the range for t and then rewrite the integrand in terms of t?

Comment: I did this and wrote my integrand as             ie^(it)(e^(2it)+1) dz. The range i used was 0 to Pi. Would this be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation is fine.

Here is another way: Along $C$ one has $z\bar z=1$, hence
$$\int_C(z^2+z\bar z)\>dz =\int_C(z^2+1)\>dz=\left({z^3\over3}+z\right)\Biggr|_1^{-1}=-{8\over3}\ .$$

Comment: Ah i see. May I ask why along C zz*=1? Also, does my particulater method make sense?

Comment: Read the first line of my answer! – You yourself have used explicitly that along $C$ one has $z\bar z=1$.